# How to insert table 1 to table 2 as daily date based from table 1 id=1 to table 2 daily by auto id creation?

Tags: sql

I want to insert and store daily date based table 1 id=1 (inserting) data to another table 2 (storing) on a daily basis by automatically creating ids 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc for storing from table 1 id=1 data to table 2 data like

Database Table name Table 1

| id | name | result | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user | 123_65_258 | 12-06-2021 |
| 2 | user2 | 234_65_678 | 12-06-2021 |

Next day (date 13-06-2021)

Database Table name Table 1

| id | column(1)name | column(2) result | column(3) date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user | 145_02_679 | 13-06-2021 |
| 2 | user2 | 235-05_357 | 13-06-2021 |

Database table name table2 select from table1 id=1

| id | coulme(1) date | coulme(2) data1 | coulme(3)data2 | coulme(4)data3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12-06-2021 | 123 | 65 | 258 |
| 2 | 13-06-2021 | 145 | 02 | 679 |

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which Database you are using. If you are using Oracle Database or any other database, we can achieve this by using the Triggers.

Here we are maintaining the ID of TABLE1 in TABLE1_ID, so that it will be useful for querying the history.

table2_seq: this is the sequence object created in Oracle.

The Trigger Code is as follows:

```
create or replace TRIGGER dv_trig_table1
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON TABLE1
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
v_date TABLE2.COLUMN1_DATE%TYPE;
-- MAIN
BEGIN
 SELECT MAX(COLUMN1_DATE) into v_date
  FROM TABLE2 
  WHERE TABLE1_ID = :NEW.ID;
   IF v_date IS NULL OR v_date < :NEW.date THEN
      INSERT INTO TABLE2(ID,TABLE1_ID, COLUMN1_DATE, DATA1, DATA2, DATA3)
      VALUES(table2_seq.nextval,:NEW.ID, :NEW.DATE, SUBSTR(:NEW.RESULT,1,3),SUBSTR(:NEW.RESULT,5,2),SUBSTR(:NEW.RESULT,8,3)) ;        
   END IF;
END;
```